# Problems with boost::read_graphviz in GitHub actions

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph, conan

I use Conan in the project to install boost 1.74.0. When I try to call `read_graphviz` function I get such error in GitHub actions while building:

> undefined reference to `boost::detail::graph::read_graphviz_new

I include only `<boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>` header from boost library.

On my computer everything is ok, but I installed boost on my own - without Conan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just forgot to add `target_link_libraries(project_name boost_graph boost_regex)`